# Using Frobenius method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

I know how to use the Frobenius Method for power series, but it can 
only be used for second order equations? All the examples that i've seen use 2nd order equations.

Comment: http://docsdrive.com/pdfs/sciencepublications/jmssp/2005/3-7.pdf

Comment: @Moo LOL. I just wanted to link to the same article.

Comment: @ProfessorVector: Nice to see that someone was thinking along the same lines!

Comment: Try $y'''-2 \left(3 x^2-1\right) y'^3=0,y(0)=0,y'(0)=1,y''(0)=0$

Comment: You can use it for $n$-th order problems of the appropriate type and there is probably a version for systems of ODEs with regular singular points, but, I have enough trouble with $n=2$, so, I'm content to stop there in my teaching.

Comment: The solution is $y=\arctan x$ 
With power series method it's relatively easy to get the solution. BTW: Even Mathematica can't solve it