# Frobenius Method on higher degrees

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

I would like to know if the Frobenius Method works on higher degree ODEs (3rd and so on). I tried to search some literature, articles etc on this matter, however I could not find anything except this: [Using Frobenius method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2351723/using-frobenius-method) .

The article linked on that question says we can generalize it for higher degree ODEs. But I am usure about the results achieved by the authors. The thing is: the article does not seem to be very formal, rigorous. So I would like to know your thoughts on this matter.

Can we use the method on higher degrees ODEs? Do you know any article on this matter?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, if you can write the ODE as $x^na_n(x)y^{(n)}(x)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}x^ka_k(x)y^{(k)}(x)+a_0(x)y(x)=r(x)$ where all the coefficient functions $a_k(x)$ and $r(x)$ are analytical, $a_n(0)\ne 0$. Then the leading terms on the left side form a Cauchy-Euler equation that is functionally equivalent to the indicial equation.

Comment: Hmm I guess I understand now. But what about the singular points and the expansion around a $x_0$? Do these remain the same? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you find the singular points as usual as the roots of the leading coefficient. Then decide the regularity by considering the multiplicity of that root in all the following coefficients.